# Probability of rolling two dice

Tags: probability, dice

> Consider two dice, each one having one face showing the letter a, two faces
> showing the letter b, and the remaining three faces showing the letter c. You roll each >die once, independently of the other die.
>
> What is the sample space?
>
> Define the events:
>
> A = "at least one of the two dice shows the letter b on its top face"
>
> B = "both dice show the same letter on their top faces".
>
> Determine Pr(A), Pr(B), and Pr(A | B).

S={(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,a),(c,c)}

S={(i,j):  a≤i≤c   a≤j≤c}

∴|S|=9

A={(a,b),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b)}

∴|A|=5

B={(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)}

∴|B|=3

∴Pr(A)=5/9

∴Pr(B)=3/9

Pr(A∩B)= 5/9 x 3/9 = 5/27

∴Pr(A│B)=5/9

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You should take into consideration that the outcomes in your sample space are not equiprobable since the individual die rolls of a, b, c are not equiprobable.  For instance the probability of (c,c) is $\frac9{36}$ while the probability of (a,a) is just $\frac{1}{36}$

Comment: so Pr(B) = 1/36 + 4/36 + 9/36 = 14/36 = 7/18 ?

Comment: That looks right to me!  :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!